# How do mobile OS creators implement server push?

Tags: android, ios, tcp, push, keep-alive

Most of you are aware that iOS and Android use push notifications to inform the phone of any arbitrary event. I am interested in how one would implement such a server-initiated notification system. As the clients most probable use NAT, the server can't open a new TCP connection to them.

As far as I can see, the phone only has TCP and UDP connectivity. TCP uses keepalive to terminate the connection on the server after some idle time. Although keepalive can be disabled completely, that would expose the server to all sorts of DoS attacks by creating lots of connection contexts.

So I think there is some kind of timeout involved after which the phone re-establishes the connection. Additionally, if using TCP connection with disabled keepalive, how are changing IP addresses on the phone handled? Or does the phone establish a new connection periodically? What are the used timers?

Hope somebody knows a bit more about it.

**UPDATE to clearify**: I do not want to use iOS or Android Libraries (APNS or GCMS). I want to know how Google/Apple implemented it on the lower OSI Transport- and Networklayer (APNS and GCMS are Application layer or at least above Transportlayer). This is a very TCP specific question, that has nothing todo with iOs or Android programming.

Comment: Broad overview of Apple push notification can be found here:[Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

Comment: I am not interested in how I need to program iOS/Android to receive push notifications. I want to know how Google/Apple does it on the server side - this is more of an network engingeering question. The basic question is how to establish a bidirectional connection between a server, and a client which is subject to constant IP change/firewalling/NAT an possible occasionally not reachable at all. Apple/Google do this somehow, and obviously their approach has proven viable.